# Как исправить ошибку парсинга

Tags: java, android, firebase

написал код пытаюсь парсить firebase realtime
NotificationFragment.java

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {


    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView name;
    TextView city_text;
    TextView jobs;
    TextView freelance;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    private NotificationsViewModel notificationsViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("Info");



        name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        city_text = view.findViewById(R.id.city_text);
        jobs = view.findViewById(R.id.jobs);
        freelance = view.findViewById(R.id.freelance);
        profile_image = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                name.setText(user.getName());
                if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_logo);
                }else{
                    Glide.with(NotificationsFragment.this).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.nikita.mozhaev.exchange.system.User does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в классе `User` конструктор без параметров.